# (excel) How to return an array from a sum of ranges?

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, range

I'm setting up a morphological table that will have to go through potentially a couple hundred items, so it's desirable for this process to not be done by hand.

Here's a small summary of the situation:

|  | fin | eng | op | fli |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| C | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| D | 1 | 4 | 7 | 2 |

The first column holds named **ranges** A through D which have associated values from the 4 **categories** in row 1.
In a second table we create **configurations** based on which features are selected, something like this:

| Config 1 | Config 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| C | D |

What I'm looking for is a formula that would read for each configuration which named range is selected, add the score for each category and return it in a simple array. Something like

Config 1 {3,6,9,13}, Config 2 {2,7,12,6}

So far I've found that the Indirect formula works exactly the way I want but I have to manually input each range. Something like:

```
=INDIRECT(A1)+INDIRECT(A2)
```

I've played around with different permutations of sum functions but instead of returning the arrays it returns the sum of the first values.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1:A2))
```

Amy suggestion would be welcome.
I know this would probably be much simpler with code but this study needs to be done in excel..

Comment: Maybe `=SUM(INDIRECT(A1):INDIRECT(A2))` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this sums every single value in the arrays and returns a single value.

Comment: You could work out column totals for the selected rows using an Mmult formula, but that wouldn't be using named ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question as it doesn't use named ranges, but you could try something like this:

```
=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,4,1,0),$B$2:$E$5*COUNTIF(INDEX($H$2:$I$3,0,ROW()-ROW($A$7)+1),$A$2:$A$5))
```

[image]

Comment: And that did the trick! Thank you so much for your help!